# Indexed PDF files not returning with google search

Tags: google-search, google-search-appliance

As the title suggests, I've managed to configure my GSA to crawl my PDF files.  They are displayed on a listing page with links to them so that the URLs can be crawled and added to a  specific collection (referred to as "My-PDFs" in this posting).

The crawl succeeds, and I can see the following in the GSA Crawl Diagnostics for the "My-PDFs" collection:

**CRAWL DIAGNOSTICS**

```
 File/Directory                             | Crawl Status

 http://mydomain.com/Listings/MyPdfs.aspx   | Crawled: New Document
 http://mydomain.com/mypdfs/cat1/issue5.pdf | Crawled: New Document
 http://mydomain.com/mypdfs/cat2/issue4.pdf | Crawled: New Document
 http://mydomain.com/mypdfs/cat3/issue2.pdf | Crawled: New Document
 http://mydomain.com/mypdfs/cat4/issue3.pdf | Crawled: New Document
 http://mydomain.com/mypdfs/cat5/issue1.pdf | Crawled: New Document
```

**The Crawl diagnostics for a single file**:

> **More information about this page**
>
> - Link to this page
> - Cached version not available
> - PageRank: Not Available
> - Last Modified:
> - Number of links on this page to crawled pages: Unknown
> - Number of crawled pages that link to this page: Unknown
> - This page is in the following collections:
>
>   - My-PDFs

However, when searching using the GSA Test center on the same 'My-PDFs' collection, the PDF files will not return.  I'm making sure to use the appropriate front end selection in the Test Center, and also the correct collection ('My-PDFs'), and then using keywords from the document.  I've also tried using the filenames of the documents, but still no results.  I always get:

> Your search - TestKeyword - did not match any documents.
>   No pages were found containing "TestKeyword".

(Obviously, using actual keywords)

Any ideas?

**NOTE:** Using GSA 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a corruption on our GSA device.  Any new collections created after a certain date appear to be crawled but are not able to be searched.  Existing collections that previously worked can continue to update but new ones cannot.

Replacing the GSA device with new hardware has been the only solution that has worked so far.